# How do I assign a particular row + column value a variable in python via Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

I am trying to use values, found in a certain row and column of data frames, in a function being used on separate data frames in later cells. Can I assign values in particular rows & columns of data frames variables? For instance, I have this df:

[df4avg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RPXg.png)

and I want to take the associated COUNT_RATE value from the CORRECTED WAVELENGTH value 120.06 in row 10 and assign it as a variable. How do I do this?

Comment: If `CORRECTED WAVELENGTH` is unique, you can use `df4avg[df4avg['CORRECTED WAVELENGTH']==120.06]['COUNT_RATE']` to get the desired value. You can then assign it to a variable etc.

Comment: @Tim, thank you! Even better than I was hoping for.

Comment: Sounds like this is a `pandas` dataframe question, not something particular to Jupyter notebooks.